# What are the main differences between the vsphere_guest and vmware_guest Ansible modules and which should I use?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, ansible, vmware-vcenter

The vmware_guest is the newer module. I've been playing around with the vsphere_guest module, but facing some issues.

- http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vsphere_guest_module.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/vmware_guest_module.html

There is not the much information on the internet and the documentation doesn't tell me either. Functionality seems fairly similar.

What is the main differences between vsphere_guest and vmware_guest and which Ansible module should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vsphere_guest` is based on outdated [PySphere](https://github.com/itnihao/pysphere) library and is available since Ansible 1.6.

`vmware_guest` (and bunch of other `vmware_...` companion modules) is based on modern [pyVmomi](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi) library from VMware and was introduced in Ansible 2.2.

`vsphere_guest` is stable, but will never get any updates.
`vmware_guest` is new (read, may have some bugs) and will get updates (some new features are already planned for Ansible 2.3).

If you are in older environment use `vsphere_guest`, otherwise adopt `vmware_guest`.